# React returning li with onClick func, initaliazing straight away

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please excuse me if this is only some very simple mistake, because I am still only very new to react.

I have the following code in my component:

```
handleClick = (mathItem) => {
    alert(this.props.obj[mathItem]);
}

this.props.mathItems.map(mathItem => {
    return <li onClick={this.handleClick(mathItem)}>{mathItem}</li>
})
```

I want the button to alert the content within when clicked but it is alerting them before the page loads and not working when clicked.

I couldn't find anything on this issue and would really appreciate any help at all, thanks!

Comment: `onClick={e => this.handleClick(mathItem)}` or `{onClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)(mathItem)}`

Comment: This worked, thanks!